# Jacobi Elliptic Function Solution using DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions

I am happy that I have a solution to a particular differential equation by hand:

```
eq = 2 * D[psi[x], {x,1}]^2 == (psi[x]^2 + f0^2)*(2(1-f0^2) - psi[x]^2) + (2*ju^2/f0^2)
```

We can write this as

```
eq = 2 * D[psi[x], {x,1}]^2 == (an^2 + psi[x]^2)(bn^2 - psi[x]^2)
```

where

```
an = Sqrt[- ( 1 - (3/2) f0^2) + Sqrt[(1 - (f0^2)/2)^2 + 2 ju^2/f0^2] ];
bn = Sqrt[+ ( 1 - (3/2) f0^2) + Sqrt[(1 - (f0^2)/2)^2 + 2 ju^2/f0^2] ];

mn = (bn^2) / (an^2 + bn^2);
m1n = 1 - mn //FullSimplify;

solpsi[x_] = Sqrt[an^2 * mn] * JacobiSD[x*Sqrt[(an^2 + bn^2)/2], mn ];
```

This solution can be verified:

```
JEFrules = {JacobiCD[x_,mn_] -> Sqrt[1 - (1-mn)*JacobiSD[x, mn]^2]
        ,JacobiND[x_,mn_] -> Sqrt[1 + mn*JacobiSD[x, mn]^2] }
lhs = 2 * D[solpsi[x], {x,1}]^2/.JEFrules;
rhs = (an^2 + solpsi[x]^2)(bn^2 -solpsi[x]^2);
lhs - rhs //Simplify
```

with output equal to zero as expected.

**If I now pretend that I don't know the solution**, I can't obtain this solution `solpsi` using `DSolve`. How can I solve my original differential equation, without needing to do the subsequent hand manipulations with MMA? Do I need to use something other than DSolve?

For ease: my attempt to solve directly using either

```
eq = 2 * D[psi[x], {x,1}]^2 == (psi[x]^2 + f0^2)*(2(1-f0^2) - psi[x]^2) + (2*ju^2/f0^2);
sol = DSolve[{eq, psi[0] == 0}, psi[x], x]
```

or

```
eq = 2 * D[psi[x], {x,1}]^2 == (an^2 + psi[x]^2)(bn^2 - psi[x]^2)
sol = DSolve[{eq, psi[0] == 0}, psi[x], x]
```

both provide very weird solutions, which certainly aren't as pleasant as the above `solpsi`; I'm not even sure they are equivalent when they clearly should be!

A final example, with output included:

```
eq = Sqrt[2]*D[psi[x], {x,1}] == Sqrt[(an^2 + psi[x]^2)(bn^2 - psi[x]^2)]
sol = DSolve[{eq, psi[0] == 0}, psi[x], x]
```

Output:

```
{{psi[x] -> InverseFunction[(I*EllipticF[I*ArcSinh[Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[f0/(-2*f0 + 3*f0^3 + Sqrt[4*f0^2 - 4*f0^4 + f0^6 + 8*ju^2])]*#1], -((-2*f0 + 3*f0^3 + Sqrt[4*f0^2 - 4*f0^4 + f0^6 + 8*ju^2])/(2*f0 - 3*f0^3 + Sqrt[4*f0^2 - 4*f0^4 + f0^6 + 8*ju^2]))]*Sqrt[1 - (2*f0*#1^2)/(2*f0 - 3*f0^3 + Sqrt[4*f0^2 - 4*f0^4 + f0^6 + 8*ju^2])]*Sqrt[1 + (2*f0*#1^2)/(-2*f0 + 3*f0^3 + Sqrt[4*f0^2 - 4*f0^4 + f0^6 + 8*ju^2])])/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[f0/(-2*f0 + 3*f0^3 + Sqrt[4*f0^2 - 4*f0^4 + f0^6 + 8*ju^2])]*Sqrt[-2*f0^4 + (2*ju^2)/f0^2 + f0^2*(2 - 3*#1^2) - #1^2*(-2 + #1^2)]) & ][x/Sqrt[2]]}}
```

Clearly not `solpsi`!
Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Spell `psi`/`Psi` consistently? ;-)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Gah! Curse my attempt to create a MWE... I'll correct it, but the problem still stands I think! Thanks for your sharp eyes

Comment: I get `bn JacobiSN[(an x)/Sqrt[2], -(bn^2/an^2)]`, which is certainly simple. I didn't check equivalence though.

Comment: That's very odd... May I ask for you to provide a snippet of your code? Or have you just copied and pasted my lines above? I have added my typical outputs above, in terms of InverseFunctions, EllipticF and ArcSinh... oh, I think you've done DSolve without using the `an` or `bn` expressions right?

Comment: `eq = 2*D[psi[x], {x, 1}]^2 == (an^2 + psi[x]^2) (bn^2 - psi[x]^2);
sol = DSolve[{eq, psi[0] == 0}, psi, x]` -- it was one of the codes you posted, but with the spelling fix.

Comment: I see... I can reproduce this one if I clear the definition of `an` and `bn` as mentioned. If you try and solve the previous equation without these defintions, you obtain a similar issue: `eq = 2 * D[psi[x], {x,1}]^2 == (psi[x]^2 + f0^2)*(2(1-f0^2) - psi[x]^2) + (2*ju^2/f0^2);`
`sol = DSolve[{eq, psi[0] == 0}, psi[x], x]`. Good to know that though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Michael for starting this approach. Without specifying `an` or `bn`, we obtain a solution like:

```
bn JacobiSN[(an x)/Sqrt[2], -(bn^2/an^2)]
```

This is secretly equivalent to the `psisol` form as desired above, by using an RIR transform, described in the wiki page and some textbooks - [relevant section of wiki page linked here.](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Jacobi_elliptic_functions#/Other_Jacobi_transformations).

It is then possible to manipulate the SN function into the SD form required. A priori, I am not sure if MMA can find this form, so I will leave this question open for the time being.

EDIT; from the solution above, it's actually quite easy to algebraically solve for the required forms of `mn` and `m1n` which exactly match our expected solution. Problem solved with a few equations solving each of the arguments!

Comment: So what is the exact transformation?

Comment: It is the transform linked in the table; `pq(u,m) = gamma_{pq} (pq)' (k' u, -m/m')`. One can identify the relevant result from this (where we relate `sd` to `sn` using this). However, obtaining this directly from MMA is still challenging.

Comment: If you use it often in your work, you can define a transformation rule.

Comment: Of course you are correct, one could use a manual transformation. The real challenge I think is identifying what `m` and `m'` are here though from this form. They should be the same as the `mn` and `m1n` as defined in my original statement - in traditional JEF notation, here `k^2 = m` and `k'^2 = m'`. It is trivial on paper when ones knows what the forms are; it is not so clear to me using MMA directly!

Comment: Turns out if it's not Sunday and we turn our minds on for a second, it's relatively trivial to solve for these factors as well algebraically once we have the solution! Problem fully wrapped up now. Thank you all